# Where can I find a large set of user avatar photos?

Tags: stock-images

I'm creating a demo account for a product I'm working on and need about 500 photos of people's faces. uifaces.com offers this, but the images are very low resolution (128px square at the largest).

Any ideas where I can find such a set of faces that can be used commercially?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because its not a design question